# How do download a file from url in Python

Tags: python, urllib2, wget

I want to download a file in Python shell like files get downloaded into browser.
Yes, I know there are multiple ways like curl, wget, url retrieve etc. but here in all the cases, file name is not the same as original file.
 Like if I want to download file from this url:

http://www.siemens.com/investor/pool/en/investor_relations/financial_publications/speeches_and_presentations/110405_trading_update_q2_11.pdf

I want to download the file from this url as it get downloaded in browser, with the same name as original.

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget

There is a simple option. Not familiar with Python as well as other languages.

Comment: hi i know this option ,i have mentioned my requirement. here if i use wget, it does not give me real name of file ,but it does gives me name extracted from url .like for this 'http://ir.paalp.com/External.asp?L=I&from=du&ID=63563&B=789' it will give me External.asp as file name, but that is not real name actually .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2.7

[urllib.urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)

Comment: i know this option too, i want to have real name of file, like we get while downloading form browser.

Comment: use this  file_name = url.split('/')[-1]